# Jackson not recognizing 'is' Fields unless annoated with @JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson

I have discovered the following problem whenever I have an "is" field in my JSON String Jackson doesn't detect it without the additional @JsonProperty Tag. Before reporting this as a Bug, I wanted to make sure this is not caused by me. The `UnmappedPropertyHandler` interface is just a method with an @JsonAnySetter to report any unknown fields, which it does for the "is" Fields whenever they are not annotated with @JsonProperty and their name between the ( ).

```
public class Event implements UnmappedPropertyHandler {

    private boolean expired, isCommunity, isPersonal, active;

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return expired;
    }

    public boolean isCommunity() {
        return isCommunity;
    }

    public boolean isPersonal() {
        return isPersonal;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
```

Snippet of the JSON String I'm parsing.

```
{
  "id": "5c7cb0d00000000000000000",
  "activation": "2022-06-01T16:00:00.000Z",
  "startString": "-11d 17h 33m 47s",
  ....
  "isPersonal": true,
  "isCommunity": true,
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson apparently scans the class that you pass in for getters and setters
and then use those methods for serialization and deserialization.

"Get", "Set", "is" are eliminated and what remains in those methods will be used as Json field.

Hence your "isCommunity" is changed into "community" and so on.

Comment: So there is no way around needing to annotate these fields with @JsonProperty to make sure they are not ignored?

Comment: Guess so. However, you can work to make these changes in your configuration files(this will not result in 100% consistency though)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jackson will read methods starting by `get` or `set`, so you'd have to call your methods `getIsCommunity` and `setIsCommunity`, and it would map the value to the correct field, although I am not sure it is a better solution than an annotation.